# if <select> duplicate data in table then <select> is disabled

Tags: html, jquery

If I choose `Mathematic` in major, `Chong` and `Long` in the name and `3.45` and `2.78` in grade are disabled. It's disable from information in a table.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id=example width=800px font-size="18">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>major</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Mathematic</td>
          <td>Chong</td>
          <td>3.45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mathematic</td>
          <td>long</td>
          <td>2.78</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>computer </td>
          <td>zhan</td>
          <td>4.00 </td>
        </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<label for="major">major</label>
<select class=" major " name="major " id="major ">
<option value="Mathematic ">Mathematic</option>
<option value="computer ">computer</option>
</select>

<label for="name">Name</label>
<select class="name" name="name" id="name">
  <option value="1">chong</option>
  <option value="2">long</option>
  <option value="3">zhan</option>
</select>

<label for="grade">Grade</label>
<select class=" grade " name="grade " id="grade ">
<option value="3.45 ">3.45</option>
<option value="2.78 ">2.78</option>
<option value="4.00 ">4.00</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your HTML markup is badly formed. Tags such as the closing `td` tag (`</td>`) are not optional. The nesting of elements is important too

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius while not idea, `</td>` *is* optional:  `<td>` : *The end tag may be omitted, if it is immediately followed by a <th> or <td> element or if there are no more data in its parent element.*

Comment: ```label``` is also wrong in your ```html```, you need to close your attribute value with ```"```

Comment: @freedomn-m is correct, but words cannot express how much I *hate* that about HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 100% agreed!

Comment: haha - indeed that is true and I feel your pain.

Comment: I'm too quick to type, sorry.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Indeed, missing end tags is pretty nasty - but I dislike *misinformation* much more :)

Comment: oooh - sounds like a wee dig at my expense there @freedomn-m nice!

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius well, my first comment clearly stated that already :)  (and I hate finding typos in my old comments... *while not **ideal**.*)